# [Golang ]why bufio reader change the strings reader?

Tags: go

The code follows ==

```
s := strings.NewReader("ABCDEFGJHIJK")
fmt.Printf("pa is %d\n ", s.GetValueI()) //GetValueI() returns the value of r.i

br := bufio.NewReader(s)
fmt.Printf("papa is %d\n ", s.GetValueI())

cc, _ := br.ReadByte()
fmt.Printf("%c\n", cc)
fmt.Printf("papapa is %d\n ", s.GetValueI())
```

The prints shows:
pa is 0
papa is 0
A
papapa is 12

So weired Results.. 
why papapa is 12 when bufio call ReadByte() ?
It really confuse me a lot ..

Answer (score 2):

The point of a buffered reader is to read the data stream more efficiently, no matter what size reads are requested.

When you call `ReadByte`, if the internal buffer is empty, it calls its internal `fill()` method to refill the buffer, which in this case consumes the entire `strings.Reader`. The single byte is then returned from this internal buffer.

Comment: @xie-jinke, to recap, the whole point of buffered reader is buffering the data it reads. Imagine you wrap an `os.File`, not `strings.Reader` into a `bufio.Reader` and then read byte-by-byte. Without buffering, reading each byte would require performing a syscall asking the kernel to reach for the file's data -- to get only a single data back. Sure, the kernel buffers filesystem operations in itself but making a syscall is a costly operation. By using buffering, you allow the reader ask the kernel for several kilobytes of data at once and then serve your byte-sized reads from the buffer.

Comment: @xie-jinkie, for that matter, once you've wrapped a reader into a `bufio.Reader` instance, you must not make any assumptions about what data have already been read from the underlying reader. From this point on, you must use only the buffered reader to do all the reads from the underlying reader. The same applies to buffered writers: you can't know what data was already sent to the underlying writer -- until you call the buffered writer's `Flush()` method, and it will complete w/o returning an error.

Comment: Thanks about the detailed explanation . I got the bufio design point .